# Broadcastreceiver working in emulator but not in device

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm try to configure a Broadcastreceiver with PHONE_STATE. This is my code:

```
<receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Class:

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("TAG","ESTAMOS DENTRO!!");
    MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(phoneListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}

public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener{
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber){
        switch (state){
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                Log.d("DEBUG","IDLE");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                Log.d("DEBUG","OFFHOOK");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                Log.d("DEBUG","RINGING: " + incomingNumber);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

This works perfectly in my emulator (Nougat), but when I try to use it in my devide (7), not working, I don't see anything in logcat..

I've tried with priority or without it. With exported/enabled and without it. Nothing.

Any ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Now works wit other device, it would be a problem form my device.
Thanks